# How can I add padding between two images

Tags: html, css

I want to make a layout like in the picture below

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzUFt.png)

I tried it with this code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column2 {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column2">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/700" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/320x173" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/320x172" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

But i can't add padding between `320x173` and `320x172` images. (I need this in `1366x1080` resolution) How can i `padding` to this? I need the final result to be like in the image attached

Comment: why dont you add a margin on your first image  `<img src="https://placehold.it/320x173" style="width:100%; margin: 5px;">` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`grid-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) layout by set `grid` to the `display` like `display: grid;` to make columns and rows for your layout and use the [`grid-column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap) and [`grid-row-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/row-gap) to control space between rows
and columns and you can simply create particular number of columns and row like

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

the above will create 2 equal columns and 2 equal rows and if you don't want equal rows and columns you can simply specify the size of each row of column according to the size of its parent

```
grid-template-rows: 200px 150px;
grid-template-columns: 102px 50px;
```

the above will create 2 rows and columns where the 2 rows first one used to have `200px` and second will have `150px` and the same on the `columns`.

but here is an example with your own code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*.column2 {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

Clearfix (clear floats)
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
padding: 5px;
} */

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.column {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column2">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/700" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/320x173" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/320x172" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Will this do?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row > div {
  margin: 5px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.column img {height: 50%;}
.column img:nth-of-type(1) {margin-bottom: 5px;}
.column img:nth-of-type(2) {margin-top: 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column2">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/700" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/320x173" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/320x172" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.lg-img-container, .sm-img-container {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;    
    justify-content: center;
}

.lg-img-container img, .sm-img-container img{
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="lg-img-container">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/700" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="sm-img-container">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/320x173" style="width:100%">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/320x172" style="width:100%">
        </div>
      </div>
```